# 2sxc - Field with HTML content

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I need a field to store content with html code like:

```
This is my text<br>Text after paragraph
```

However, string fields will replace every symbol and outputs it with entity names like  `&lt;br&gt;` when I output it in @Content.mystringwithhtml.

Is there any workaround besides creating a JS function to decode it?

Best regards,
João

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use the HTML.Raw function
create a multi line content field and choose the default wysiwyg edititor.  THen add your HTML in teh editors html or raw view.

then in your view use this:

@Html.Raw(Content.YourField)

Comment: The '<p></p>' it adds around the content does not help, but otherwise it works. Thanks.

Comment: Your welcome. There is a replace function in razor you can use to wrap around the content.yourfield if there are specific characters you need to remove.

Comment: Thanks. Rather weird syntax, but works:
'@Html.Raw(@Content.filed.Replace("<p>", "").Replace("</p>", ""))'

Comment: Did you switch the editor to raw/HTML mode when you were entering your data. It's under the advanced tool button/menu. Then it should not wrap your content. I use this for inserting HTML content from services like google maps iframes etc

Comment: It does. I delete the "<p>", but when I save it gets added again, even in code/raw mode.

Comment: That is odd. It does not do that in my app